# Mortgage calculator with Swing for Helsinki MOOC

Tags: java, beginner, calculator, swing, finance

New to Java, just finished the Helsinki MOOC course. I programmed a basic mortgage calculator as my first solo project and while it works, I have a few questions about coding style:

1. The listener and ui classes are cluttered with variables at the top. Is this acceptable or is there a cleaner way of organizing it?
2. Is initializing the variables in the `CalcLogic` class as strings and then creating new `BigDecimal` variables in the methods an accepted way of using `BigDecimal`, or would it better to initialize the variables as BigDecimals?
3. Are there any other coding style or logic issues that are noticeable?

`CalcLogic` class:

```
package mortgagecalculator.logic;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

/**
 * Logic for mortgage calculator.
 * Input variables for home value, loan term, etc. and outputs EMI, total payment, etc.
 * 
 */

public class CalcLogic {

    //Variables for calculating mortgage. propTax, homeIns, etc are not initialized in constructor
    private String principal = "0";
    private String downPayment = "0";
    private String interestRate = "0";
    private int loanTerm = 0;
    private String propTax = "0";
    private String homeIns = "0";
    private String hoaFee = "0";
    private String pmiRate = "0";

    public void setPrincipal(String principal) {
        this.principal = principal;
    }

    public void setDownPayment(String downPayment) {
        this.downPayment = downPayment;
    }

    public void setInterest(String interestRate) {
        this.interestRate = interestRate;
    }

    public void setLoanTerm(int loanTerm) {
        this.loanTerm = loanTerm;
    }    

    public void setPropTax(String propTax) {
        this.propTax = propTax;
    }

    public void setHomeIns(String homeIns) {
        this.homeIns = homeIns;
    }

    public void setHOAfee(String hoaFee) {
        this.hoaFee = hoaFee;
    }

    public void setPMIrate(String pmiRate) {
        this.pmiRate = pmiRate;
    }

    //Returns principal minus downpayment 
    public BigDecimal getInitialAmount() {
        return new BigDecimal(this.principal).subtract(new BigDecimal(this.downPayment));
    }

    //Returns twenty percent of principal
    public BigDecimal twentyDown() {
        BigDecimal twenty = new BigDecimal("20").divide(new BigDecimal("100"));
        return new BigDecimal(this.principal).multiply(twenty);
    }

    public BigDecimal monthlyInterest() {
        return new BigDecimal(this.interestRate).divide(new BigDecimal("100"))
                             .divide(new BigDecimal("12"), 8, RoundingMode.UP);
    }

    public BigDecimal monthlyPMI() {

        try {
           BigDecimal result = getInitialAmount().divide(new BigDecimal(this.pmiRate).divide(new BigDecimal("100"))
                                 .divide(new BigDecimal("12")), 2, RoundingMode.UP);
           return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
           return BigDecimal.ZERO;
        }

    }

    public BigDecimal additionalTax() {
        BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(this.propTax);
        sum = sum.add(new BigDecimal(this.homeIns)).add(new BigDecimal(this.hoaFee));      
        return sum;
    }    

    public BigDecimal getEMI() {
        BigDecimal value = monthlyInterest().add(BigDecimal.ONE);
        value = value.pow(this.loanTerm * 12);

        BigDecimal numerator = value.multiply(monthlyInterest()).multiply(getInitialAmount());
        BigDecimal denominator = value.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);

        return numerator.divide(denominator, 2, RoundingMode.UP);

    }

    public BigDecimal monthlyPayment() {
        BigDecimal result = getEMI().add(monthlyPMI()).add(additionalTax());
        return result;
    }

    public BigDecimal totalInterest() {
        BigDecimal result = getEMI().multiply(new BigDecimal(this.loanTerm * 12));
        result = result.subtract(getInitialAmount());
        return result;
    }

    //Returns month where principal payments first exceed interest payments
    public int amortMonth() {
        BigDecimal remaining = getInitialAmount().setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.loanTerm * 12; i++) {

            BigDecimal interPay = remaining.multiply(monthlyInterest()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);            
            BigDecimal princPay = getEMI().subtract(interPay).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);

            if (princPay.compareTo(interPay) == 1) {
                return i + 1;
            }

            remaining = remaining.subtract(princPay).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING);

        }

        return 0;
    } 

}
```

`CalcListener` class:

```
package mortgagecalculator.ui;

import mortgagecalculator.logic.CalcLogic;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class CalcListener implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField principal;
    private JTextField downPayment;
    private JTextField interestRate;
    private JTextField loanTerm;
    private JTextField propTax;
    private JTextField homeIns;
    private JTextField hoaFee;
    private JTextField pmiRate;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField EMI;
    private JTextField monthlyFee;
    private JTextField totalInt;
    private JTextField changeMonth;
    private CalcLogic calc;

    public CalcListener(JTextField principal, JTextField downPayment, JTextField interestRate,
                        JTextField loanTerm, JTextField propTax, JTextField homeIns,
                        JTextField hoaFee, JTextField pmiRate, JTextField EMI,
                        JTextField monthlyFee, JTextField totalInt, JTextField changeMonth, JButton button) {
        this.principal = principal;
        this.downPayment = downPayment;
        this.interestRate = interestRate;
        this.loanTerm = loanTerm;
        this.propTax = propTax;
        this.homeIns = homeIns;
        this.hoaFee = hoaFee;
        this.pmiRate = pmiRate;
        this.button = button;
        this.EMI = EMI;
        this.monthlyFee = monthlyFee;
        this.totalInt = totalInt;
        this.changeMonth = changeMonth;
        this.calc = new CalcLogic();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if (ae.getSource() == this.button) {

            this.calc.setPrincipal(this.principal.getText());
            this.calc.setDownPayment(this.downPayment.getText());
            this.calc.setInterest(this.interestRate.getText());
            this.calc.setLoanTerm(Integer.parseInt(this.loanTerm.getText()));
            this.calc.setPropTax(this.propTax.getText());
            this.calc.setHomeIns(this.homeIns.getText());
            this.calc.setPMIrate(this.pmiRate.getText());
            this.calc.setHOAfee(this.hoaFee.getText());

            this.EMI.setText(this.calc.getEMI().toString());
            this.monthlyFee.setText(this.calc.monthlyPayment().toString());
            this.totalInt.setText(this.calc.totalInterest().toString());
            this.changeMonth.setText(String.valueOf(this.calc.amortMonth()));            

        }

    }
}
```

`UserInterface` class:

```
package mortgagecalculator.ui;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import mortgagecalculator.ui.CalcListener;

public class UserInterface implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField principal;
    private JTextField downPayment;
    private JTextField interestRate;
    private JTextField loanTerm;
    private JTextField propTax;
    private JTextField homeIns;
    private JTextField hoaFee;
    private JTextField pmiRate;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField EMI;
    private JTextField monthlyFee;
    private JTextField totalInt;
    private JTextField changeMonth;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Mortgage Calculator");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        createComponents(frame.getContentPane());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    private void createComponents(Container container) {
        generateVariables();
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        container.add(createInputPanel());
        container.add(this.button);
        container.add(createOutputPanel());

    }

    private void generateVariables() {
        this.principal = new JTextField("");
        this.downPayment = new JTextField("");
        this.interestRate = new JTextField("");
        this.loanTerm = new JTextField("");
        this.propTax = new JTextField("");
        this.homeIns = new JTextField("");
        this.hoaFee = new JTextField("");
        this.pmiRate = new JTextField("");
        this.EMI = new JTextField("");
        this.monthlyFee = new JTextField("");
        this.totalInt = new JTextField("");
        this.changeMonth = new JTextField("");
        this.button = new JButton("Calculate!");

        CalcListener calc = new CalcListener(this.principal, this.downPayment, this.interestRate,
                                             this.loanTerm, this.propTax, this.homeIns, this.hoaFee,
                                             this.pmiRate, this.EMI, this.monthlyFee, this.totalInt,
                                             this.changeMonth, this.button);

        this.button.addActionListener(calc);
    }

    private JPanel createInputPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Principal"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Down Payment"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Interest Rate (in %)"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Loan term (in years)"));
        panel.add(this.principal);
        panel.add(this.downPayment);
        panel.add(this.interestRate);
        panel.add(this.loanTerm);

        panel.add(new JLabel("Property Tax (Monthly)"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Home Insurance (Monthly)"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("HOA Fees (Monthly)"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("PMI Rate (in %)"));
        panel.add(this.propTax);
        panel.add(this.homeIns);
        panel.add(this.hoaFee);
        panel.add(this.pmiRate);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createOutputPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 2));

        panel.add(new JLabel("Equated Monthly Installment"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Monthly w/ fees"));
        panel.add(this.EMI);
        panel.add(this.monthlyFee);

        panel.add(new JLabel("Total Interest Payments"));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Month where principal payments > interest"));
        panel.add(this.totalInt);
        panel.add(this.changeMonth);

        return panel;
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CalcLogic` should only deal with `BigDecimal` values; not `String` values.

Consider the symmetry of input and output:

```
class CalcLogic {
    public void       setPrinciple(String principle) { ... }
    public BigDecimal getInitialAmount() { ... }
}
```

or

```
class CalcLogic {
    public void       setPrinciple(BigDecimal principle) { ... }
    public BigDecimal getInitialAmount() { ... }
}
```

Why would you `setXxxx()` a `String` value and `getXxxx()` a `BigDecimal`?  This class deals with numbers, specifically money.  Money values go in; money values come out.

---

Along that vein, you should write the member functions following the Java Bean standard.  Instead of `monthlyInterest()`, you should name the method `getMonthlyInterest()`.

---

The `CalcListener` class is breaking encapsulation.  It requires exactly the same fields as a the `UserInterface` class, and all those fields have to be passed in the constructor.  If you add a field, you have to add code in many places to ensure the class definitions are kept in sync.

Instead, `CalcListener` could be an inner class.

```
public class UserInterface implements Runnable {

    private JTextField principal;
    // ... etc ...

    class CalcListener implements ActionListener {

        private final CalcLogic calc = new CalcLogic();

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            calc.setPrinciple(new BigDecimal(principle.getText()));
            // ... etc ...
        }
    }

    private void generateVariables() {
        // ... etc ...
        button.addActionListener(new CalcListener());
    }

    // ... etc ...
}
```

As an inner class, `CalcListener` has access to all the `private` members of `UserInterface`, so there is no need to pass them all in a call to the `CalcListener()` constructor.

It is still breaking encapsulation, albeit in a different way - one which requires a lot less code.

---

Instead of using `JTextField`, you probably want to use [`JFormattedTextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).

The `JFormattedTextField` can perform the work of converting between the display format, a `String`, and the model object, in this case a `BigDecimal`.

Use a helper function to create the `JFormattedTextField`, to set it up properly.

```
private static JFormattedTextField bigDecimalField(String initialValue, String format) {
    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(initialValue);
    JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField(value);
    DefaultFormatter fmt = new NumberFormatter(new DecimalFormat(format));
    fmt.setValueClass(value.getClass());
    DefaultFormatterFactory factory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(fmt, fmt, fmt);
    tf.setFormatterFactory(factory);

    return tf;
}
```

Create the fields like:

```
private final JFormattedTextField principle = bigDecimalField("0.00", "#.00");
// ...etc..
```

And reference the values like:

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            calc.setPrinciple((BigDecimal) principle.getValue());
            // ... etc ...
        }
```

Notice, you are no longer retrieving a text string from the field, but the actual model object ... a `BigDecimal`.

Of course, you can do better by declaring your own `BigDecimalField` class, which returns the correctly cast return value, so the caller doesn't have to cast all the time.